How can I auto stop EC2 instances when idle using cloudwatch?
I made a python script that would send data such as time since last user input, CPU usage, network I/O, etc to a websocket endpoint, which is written to a DB and then read off from it to decide if an instance needs to be stopped.
But my friends told me that using cloudwatch would be better and easier for this use case. From what I see, I can use any one metric (CPU utilization, network IO, etc) to make this decision on cloudwatch, but I doubt that would be enough to decide if an instance is actually idle. Can I really use cloudwatch alarms for my problem? If so can you provide some resources I can refer for this problem?
Thanks in advance!
P.S: I referred this post, but doesn't seem to answer my question really.

The definition of an "idle instance" is not easy. Operating Systems are always doing stuff, so it's hard to say when an instance is actually idle. Then, there's the question of how you want to start it again if there is demand. Are you looking at having a fleet of instances and just changing their quantity (eg using Auto Scaling), or is it just one instance that you want to start/stop?

@JohnRotenstein That is the reason why I felt CPU and network alone won't work and so wrote my script to collect user input timings, but not sure if that will be available in CloudWatch. We don't have any fleet set up, when an instance is stopped, we take a snapshot and terminate the instance. And when needed, we simply restore the snapshot to a new instance.

Instead of taking a snapshot, are you okay with simply using Stop and Start to turn the instance off/on? There is very little cost saving in taking a snapshot compared with keeping the disk volume around, but it is much easier to simply Start the instance when it is needed. It is probably easiest to run a script on the instance and have it monitor itself to decide when to shutdown (by issuing a sudo shutdown now -h command).

@JohnRotenstein We chose to go with snapshots since we assign the VM to users who request to connect, and in such cases we restore a VM from the snapshot and assign it to them and this is the reason why we need to stop an instance if it isn't being used. And from your comments and others' I guess the best route is to use our custom implementation here. We'll try out your suggestions. anyway thank you for the help!

Solution 1 (no extra money):
You can run your python script inside the EC2 instance and check metrics, then shut down the instance. The python file can run using user data, or cron job.
Solution 2 (costs):
We can run lambda functions periodically, and check the metrics of ec2 instances, from there you can also trigger shutdown.
You can use it as it is or with CloudWatch, but that will give you extra headache, binding CloudWatch alarms with lambda functions. But that's another way of doing it too.
Solution2 is better because lambda can log whatever happens, so you will be able to debug in future.

Yeah, lambda is something we could look at, but then again, I am not sure if the metrics from cloudwatch alone is enough to decide to terminate the instance. We wouldn't want to stop instances if a user is still using it, but isn't under heavy load.

Yes it is enough.
You see, when we make scalable highly available infras with AWS using autoscaling group.. the scalability is controlled by CloudWatch alarm itself. It triggers scale up and down. So yes you can trust it. At least do some R&D and see. Best wishes @guidingfox
